# php variable in an array

Tags: php, variables

```
 $q2=$_REQUEST['binge'];
'book2'=>array('callno'=>123006,'price'=>number_format(844,2),'desc'=>'Binge','auth'=>'Tyler Oakley','quant'=>$q2,'total'=>number_format(844,2)*$q2)
```

On this particular code, It kept displaying errors like this

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webcard_3new\Webcard\wishlist.php on line 97

I searched all over the net for finding the right answers but some are just so complex to understand...

It supposed to be that $q2 is the variable inside an array. That variable is then multiplied to the "TOTAL". but the errors kept on going.. please help!!

Comment: Can you show us the output of $q2? `var_dump($q2);`

Comment: I think instead of `'book' =>` you should write `$book =`

Comment: I just tested this code and works: `$q2= "100";

$book2 = array('callno'=>123006,'price'=>number_format(844,2),'desc'=>'Binge','auth'=>'Tyler Oakley','quant'=>$q2,'total'=>number_format(844,2)*$q2);

var_dump($book2);`

Comment: @Hackerman What did you get?

Comment: i used the is_numeric function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$q2 = filter_var($_REQUEST['binge'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

here you will have the benefit of validation where `false` is returned when someone passes a value that is not an integer.  If it is instead a float use `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` instead.

Also, consider using `$_GET`, or `$_POST` directly to have more control of the data channel.  $_REQUEST cobbles together several things into one, which sometimes may cause issues when more than one channel have the same key.

Comment: ok thanks for the recommendation... I already found it.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

The super-globals will always be strings. You need to explicitly convert them using [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php):

```
$q2 = intval($_REQUEST['binge']);
```

Also, this line:

```
'book2'=>array...
```

Should be

```
$book2 = array...
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation... I just found the error and I just fixed it a while ago.. Maybe ill use this in other projects..